# I intermittently experience SQL Server connection issues from AWS Lambda using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I have AWS Lambda function that connects over a VPC into a privately hosted SQL Server database.

I intermittently get this exception:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Since the DNS is not setup I use an IP address to connect to the SQL Server. My understanding is that the environment is stateless which means I can't make use of SQL Connection Pooling. My connection string I am currently using is:

> Data Source=xx.xx.x.xx;Initial Catalog=DbName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Pooling=false;Password=password;TrustServerCertificate=true

I have turned off connection pooling in the SQL Connection string.

I also updated my code to explicitly close the connection

```
await using var connection = new SqlConnection(AppSettings.ConnectionString);
await connection.OpenAsync();
var payrollOrderCategories = await connection.QueryAsync<Dto.Payroll.PayrollOrderCategory>(
               "SELECT Id, Name FROM PayrollOrderCategory"
           );

await connection.CloseAsync();
```

The logs also indicates the following:

> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

which proves it is not using pooling but the problem persists intermittently. The API also calls another internal service which it is always able to reach, which leads me to think it is not a network related issue on the VPC

Comment: How security group on database is configured?

Comment: Both the Inbound and Outbound indicate Protocol and Ports are set to all.

Comment: Are you not allowing security group of Lambda in the inbound rule of database EC2/RDS?

Comment: `over a VPC into a privately hosted SQL Server` why assume this is anything other than what the error says - networking issues? Such errors are *guaranteed* over public internet connections. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient [offers configurable retries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/configurable-retry-logic?view=sql-server-ver16) for exactly this scenario. Connection pooling has nothing to do with whether an environment is stateless. Never mind that Lambda isn't as stateless as you assume.

Comment: Are you using an instance name in your connection string? Instance names require an SSRP (SQL Server Resolution Protocol) lookup over udp/1434 to the SQL Browser service listening on the target machine. Being UDP it has no builtin retry mechanisms, so if there are any interruptions to the flow of UDP requests over your on-prem tunnel it will fail to resolve and so fail to connect.

Comment: In the [Introducing Configurable Retry Logic in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient v3.0.0-Preview1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/configurable-retry-logic-for-microsoft-data-sqlclient/) serverless connection issue are explicitly mentioned as a target scenario. `Configurable retry logic is, in fact, capable of eliminating completely the side effect of connection issues during warm up condition (when a serverless database is waking up after auto-pausing, usually between 30 and 60 seconds) by configuring proper number of retries covering that time interval`

Comment: I have tried Polly to resolve that type of problem. I will remove it and give the SqlClient a go

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll always have this problem if you try to connect over a WAN, especially from a cold Lambda instance. Network connections even inside the same AWS data center can be flaky. In your case you have to handle both the cold startup delays *and* the far less stable WAN connection

Comment: "My understanding is that the environment is stateless which means I can't make use of SQL Connection Pooling." just because it's stateless doesn't mean you shouldn't use connection pooling. If the app pool gets shutdown then the pool will get cleaned up anyway. Don't disable pooling unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This intermittent issue with the service can be attributed to the misconfigured route tables in the VPC. Since only two out of the three subnets were correctly configured to connect to the SQL server, the service's availability depended on which subnet was being utilized at any given time. If the traffic was routed through one of the two properly configured subnets, the service functioned normally. However, whenever the traffic happened to go through the third, misconfigured subnet, the service became unreachable. This inconsistency in routing led to the intermittent accessibility of the service.

Answer (score -1):

1. If you are experiencing this issue with multiple concurrent calls, check the instance type and connection limit.
2. Examine Lambda functions subnets. We may have accidentally picked both private and public subnets. This type of problem will arise when calls are routed over the public subnet.